# How to decrease width of the box from both right and left equally when the containing block size changes?

Tags: css

I have made a bordered box. Here is the css code:

```
.Box{
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
 
  
}
```

When I run the following CSS my box appears as shown in the image below.

[image]

Now when I try to decrease the size of the containing block of the box, till there is a margin on both sides the box remains in the middle and the margins decrease but once the margin space is over the left border becomes stationary and only the right portion starts to shrink.

[image]

In the above image, it could be seen that the margin has fully shrunken and now the left side is stationary and the right side is only shrinking

I want the box to shrink from both sides equally even when the margin is over. Please guide me on how I could achieve this. Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: The width of your box is static. The only thing that's shrinking is the margin, so when the box runs out of margin space, it starts to overflow. The solution would be to use percentage width, e.g. `width: 90%;`. If the initial size of the container is too big, you can always limit the maximum width of this box: `max-with: 700px;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS function min to make sure the box is 700pa when its container has a width greater than or equal to 700px, and thereafter it will take on the width of the container.

This snipper transitions the container width from 100vw to 100px (and vice versa) when you click the button. It has a backgound color so you can see when it is larger than the box.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  transition: width 5s linear;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.container.shrink {
  width: 100px;
}
.Box{
  height: 500px;
  width: min(700px, 100%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.container').classList.toggle('shrink');">Click me to make the container shrink/grow</button>
<div class="container">
<div class="Box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your approach if you change your `width:700px;` to `max-width:700px;`
when screen shrinks, both left and right borders will shrink with them because when the screen width is smaller your box's width will be equal to screen width.

```
.Box{
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```